# Advice for a voting / multiple rating plugin for post types other than GD Star Rating

Tags: plugins, rating, plugin-gd-star-rating, review, poll

I would like to let users of one of my WP projects to cast votes on certain post types; the type of votes cast should differ slightly according to post type. For example for one post type they might vote for things like "money value", "quality", "comfort" (imagine a hotel...) for other things they might cast votes for things like "is the article interesting?" or "helpful". For other post types there wouldn't be polls at all. And so on. I need to show average ratings in a widget and perhaps the user individual rating to be displayed along his comment (users should be registered and, on certain post types at least, post rating contextually to comment, which would function as user review as well). It would be nice if I can make it work also for BBPress plugin, since technically forum posts are custom post types, therefore users might rate forum threads for being "interesting" or "useful" for example.

I've found GD Star Rating plugin, but it seems to me a bit overcomplicated, documentation is a bit obscure (I guess it's for paid support only, but I want to be sure if it's what I really need before subscribing a license). On the other hand there's no built in support for post types, which is scheduled for release 2.0.

Is there any simple alternative? Doesn't matter if it's a free or commercial plugin, as long as it's straightforward to use and provides support for what I'd like to achieve.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wrote this plugin a while back for a client and never got around to polishing it off for general release.

https://github.com/dwenaus/bp-rate-vote-like-anything

Myself and another developer plan to launch it soon. But even as it is now, it's totally solid and very cleanly coded. I wrote it because GD Star Rating plugin was so bloated. Basically it provides a framework for you to rate or vote or like any wordpress object that has a db id - so yes a custom post type is no problem.

UPDATE: I've made the repo private until I release the plugin.

Comment: Oh that's great news Deryk, I will give it a try and eventually provide italian localization

Comment: I installed the plugin on a multisite installation but I can't find any admin panel; perhaps I will try again when the plugin is officially released, I don't need a solution asap anyway - thanks

Comment: in it's current state there is no admin panel, you'll have to do some basic coding to integrate it using hooks and filters. it should be launched in a month with admin panel and hooks and filters ready to go.

Comment: Also looking forward, I'll watch on github, assuming updates will come there.

Comment: Please post it also in the WP plugins repository, will be easier for other people to find and perhaps get more support

Comment: ongoing development will happen at guthub, and all release tags will always go to the wp plugin repository.

Comment: @Deryk Could you update the link?

Comment: i've made it a private repository until I release the plugin later on.

Comment: Great. Looking forward for the WP Plugin!